# Prevent entire row duplicates with standard SQL

Tags: sql

Lets say we have a very simple SQL table organized as follows:

```
  email_address | phone_number
  test@test.com | 5555555555
  test@test.com | 9999999999
  user@user.com | 7468382678
```

In this example, it is perfectly OK to have multiple phone numbers attached to an email address.  If I want to *prevent insertion of exact duplicates* (prevent insertion if **both** columns match), is there a way to do this using a single query?

(I'd like to avoid the obvious, "SELECT count(*) FROM db WHERE email_address='test@test.com' AND phone_number='5555555555', followed by an INSERT only if we don't find records)

I'm using a standard version of MySql, so proprietary extensions will not work in this case. (I'm aware of IF NOT EXISTS and other MS extensions)

Is there any sort of multi-column condition that I can set up to make this happen?  What is the most efficient way to do this?

Using two queries just feels wrong.

Many Thanks.

Comment: your gut feeling is right: using 2 queries *is* wrong. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no ANSI-SQL statement I am aware of. Try this MySQL statement instead:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO your_table (emai_address, phone_number) VALUES ("test@test.com", 5555555555);
```

Note: You must have a unique index spanning both your columns for this to work:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD UNIQUE KEY (email_address, phone_number);
```

Comment: I think the last comment you made might be the key.  I've tried INSERT IGNORE, and it didn't behave as I expected (even after adding a unique id).  How do I make an index 'span both columns' as you suggest?

Comment: The `ALTER TABLE` statement should do it

Answer (score 2):

One way:

```
create table contact_info
(
  email_address varchar(256) not null ,
  phone_number  varchar(10)  not null ,

  primary key clustered ( email_address , phone_number ) ,

)
```

You won't be inserting any exact duplicates. B^)

Proactively, you should be able to do something like:

```
insert contact_info
select *
from ( select <email-addr_value>   as email ,
              <phone-number_value> as phone
     ) t1
where not exists ( select * from contact_info t2
                   where t2.email_address = t1.email
                     and t2.phone_number  = t2.phone
                 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Set up a unique constraint on the table based on the two columns, so the insert fails on duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative ("old school"?) approach to the "alter table" statement in the accepted answer is to create a unique index thusly:

```
create unique index all_columns_idx on your_table(email_address, phone_number)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try DISTINCT if you only want to deal with the display?

Something like:

`SELECT DISTINCT * FROM db`